# Uniform convergence, boundedness and differentiation

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose that ⟨fn⟩ is a sequence of real valued differentiable functions
on [0, 1], ⟨fn(0)⟩ is bounded, and that ⟨f′n⟩ is uniformly bounded on [0, 1]. Show
that ⟨fn⟩ is uniformly bounded on [0, 1] and some subsequence of ⟨fn⟩ converges
uniformly on [0, 1].

I didn't really have much problem starting off from uniform convergence to uniform boundedness, but the opposite seems a bit tricky... How shall we prove this?

Comment: Why are you trying to prove the opposite? You are not being asked to.

Comment: But I am starting off from boundedness to show uniform convergence of a subsequence?

Comment: This is a standard application of Arzela _Ascoli Theorem which you can find in MSE or Wikipedia.

Comment: Oh, I see. You omitted the subsequence part, but yes. I would write down the givens and number them, one per line, and then start to prove it. Have the definition/lemma/theorem of each given handy, the proof should start showing up as you look at what you are given and go over what each one means.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try numbering them out